# Loop over a vector in data.table: filter and summarize iterating with by

Tags: r, data.table, iteration, grouping

I was making a for loop to summarize `data.table` with version 1.14.0.

I wanted to iterate over a vector because I needed to group data by a different variable each time. For doing this I only know `eval( parse( text = x))` way. Probably it's a bad idea but I don't know any other solution.

Here a vector and data.table example:

```
catvars = c( "cbmi", "anl_cHBA1C")

a = c( rep( "1",3 ), rep( "2", 3 ), rep( "3", 3 ))
b = rep( c( "2012", "2013","2014" ), each = 1 )
z = rep( c( TRUE, FALSE, TRUE ), each = 1 )
m = rep( c( NA ,"1", "1" ), each = 1)
d = rep( c( "No ttm", "Mono", "Poli" ), each = 1 )
e = rep( c( "BMI > 30", "BMI > 30", "BMI < 25" ), each = 1 )
f = rep( c( ">7", "<=7", "<=7" ), each = 1 )


DT = data.table(id = a,
                year = b,
                dm2 = z,
                exp_th = m,
                exp_th2 = d, 
                cbmi = e,
                anl_cHBA1C = f)
```

The code without loop:

```
cbmi_ttm = DT [ dm2 == TRUE , total := .N , by = .( year )
               ][ dm2 == TRUE , .( .N, total = max( total ) ),
                  by = .( year, ttm2 =  fcase( exp_th2 != "No ttm" , exp_th2 ,
                                               exp_th2 == "No ttm", "Untreated"),
                         cbmi )
                  ][, `:=` ( per = round(N/total*100, 2 ), total = NULL )]
```

I wrote the code inside the loop and iterate over `catvars`

```
for ( x in catvars ) { 
  assign (paste0( x, "DT_aut_ttm2"),
          DT [ dm2 == TRUE , total := .N, by = .( year )
               ][ dm2 == TRUE , .( .N, total = max( total )),
                  by = .( year, ttm2 =  fcase( exp_th2 != "No ttm" , exp_th2,
                                               exp_th2 == "No ttm", "Untreated" ),
                    eval( parse( text = x )))
                  ][ , ( x ) := parse
                    ][ , parse := NULL
                      ][ , `:=` (per = round( N/total*100, 2 ), total = NULL)]
          )
}
```

but gives this error:

```
"Error in eval(parse(text = x)) : object 'cbmi' not found"
```

My **intended output** is:

```
cbmiDT_aut_ttm2

   year      ttm2 N     cbmi per
1: 2012 Untreated 3 BMI > 30 100
2: 2014      Poli 3 BMI < 25 100
```

and

```
anl_cHBA1CDT_aut_ttm2

   year      ttm2 N anl_cHBA1C per
1: 2012 Untreated 3         >7 100
2: 2014      Poli 3        <=7 100
```

After triying different approaches I remove the i part (filter) and create a new data.table filtered:

```
DT_filter = DT [ dm2 == TRUE,]

for (x in catvars) {
  assign (paste0( x, "DT_aut_ttm2_nofilter"),
          DT_filter [, total := .N , by = .( year )
                     ][ , .( .N, total = max( total )),
                        by = .( year, ttm2 =  fcase( exp_th2 != "No ttm" , exp_th2,
                                                     exp_th2 == "No ttm", "Untreated" ),
                                eval( parse( text = x )))
                        ][ , ( x ) := parse
                           ][ , parse := NULL
                              ][ , `:=` (per = round( N/total*100, 2 ), total = NULL )]
          )
}
```

And It just worked.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour in data.table? Probably I haven't looked enough in the documentation but I haven't found any indication about this "problem". Is a real known problem or it's just my fault?

Do you know any clean way of obtaining the same result without `eval( parse( text = ))` ?

Do you think of any alternative approach?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't use `c` as a variable.

Comment: What is your intended output? While `for` loops can be necessary with `data.table`s, often they can be avoided (especially with groups).

Comment: your `fcase` call isn't clear. Did you really want `ttm2` to be `NA` if `exp_th2 == "No ttm`?

Comment: @r2evans I just added the intended output; So it seems a known issue the problem with group?

Comment: @langtang I added to fcase "Untreated" if `exp_th2 == "No ttm`. It's the same having `NA's` or `Untreated`, but if it's more clear for all, it's ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one possibility is to melt over your catvars, like this:

```
DT_long <- melt(DT, id.vars = setdiff(colnames(DT),catvars), measure.vars = catvars, variable.name = "catvar")
DT_long[dm2 == TRUE][
  ,total:=.N, by=.(year, catvar)][
    ,.(.N, total = max(total)), 
    by = .(year, ttm2 = fifelse(exp_th2 != "No ttm", exp_th2,"Untreated"), value, catvar)][
      ,`:=`(per = round(N/total*100, 2), total=NULL)][]
```

Output:

```
   year      ttm2    value     catvar N per
1: 2012 Untreated BMI > 30       cbmi 3 100
2: 2014      Poli BMI < 25       cbmi 3 100
3: 2012 Untreated       >7 anl_cHBA1C 3 100
4: 2014      Poli      <=7 anl_cHBA1C 3 100
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting this solution. So simple!